# Move field matching pattern to first field

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file of hundreds of lines e.g:

CAT FROG DOG PIG

DOG PIG BIRD HORSE

HORSE FROG PIG

And I wand to move any field containing "PIG" to the first field as below:

PIG CAT FROG DOG

PIG DOG BIRD HORSE

PIG HORSE FROG

Is it possible to do in an awk one liner? I was trying to reverse engineer this line I found in another thread that moves fields matching a pattern to the end but my knowledge of awk is not great:

`awk '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i~/PIG/) a[i]++; } {for(i in a){str=str $i FS; $i=""} $0=$0 FS str; $1=$1; str=""}1' file`

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: You should include some non-trivial cases in your example, e.g. 2 back to back PIGs on a line, 2 separated PIGs on a line, no PIGs on a line, etc. otherwise you're likely to get a solution that ONLY works for the one sunny-day case of exactly 1 PIG on every line.

Comment: FYI asking for a `one-liner` discourages people from helping you as it implies you care more about brevity than you do about clarity, robustness, efficiency, portability and anything else that actually matter in software. You can always cram whatever answer you get into a single line later if you really find that useful for some reason.

Comment: what to do with a field that *contains* the string `PIG`, eg, `PIGGIE`, `BIG-PIG`? and if you do include these fields is there any requirement to list the fields in a sorted order?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am a biologist by background so your pointers are useful and noted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{
    out = $1
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        out = ($i ~ /PIG/ ? $i OFS out : out OFS $i)
    }
    print out
}'
```

---

Original answer below would produce the posted expected output from the posted sample input but would fail in some of the non-trivial cases not covered by the provided sample input as the assignment to $0 in the loop resplits the record, renumbering the fields and so could skip a field:

```
awk '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i ~ /PIG/) {
            tmp = $i
            $i = ""
            $0 = tmp FS $0
        }
    }
    $1 = $1
    print
}' file
```

Comment: This works great, I am doing some clustering and adding in a single cluster centroid from a previous clustering for some comparison work so there should only be a single "PIG" per line. If there isn't something has gone wrong upstream. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner solution:

```
echo
echo "${test1}"
echo

<<<"${test1}" mawk '(NF*=!_<NF) && \
                          sub("^",FS" ")+\
                      gsub("[ \t]+"," ")' FS='PIG' OFS=''

CAT FROG DOG PIG
DOG PIG BIRD HORSE
HORSE FROG PIG
FROG DOG HORSE

PIG CAT FROG DOG 
PIG DOG BIRD HORSE
PIG HORSE FROG
```